# Gradient color for text to UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

I need to set gradient color with to colors into UITextView with white background color like in instagram stories. Example below:

[image]

Comment: It is easy to create the image you showed, but not as a text view.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show your code.

Comment: @creeperspeak I tried the article from the medium, but it works only for the UILabel. I have the usual UITextView in the code with the usual text color, I have no idea how to make the text a gradient like in the picture. I need to do this exactly in textView

Comment: @creeperspeak like instagram stories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the constraints set in the following code, but the concept should go like this:

```
    containerView = GradientView.init()
    self.view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 220).isActive = true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    containerView.backgroundColor = .white

    textView = UITextView()
    containerView.addSubview(textView)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    textView.text = "#SomeValue"
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)
    containerView.layer.mask = textView.layer.sublayers?.last
```

where GradientView is a UIView subclass similar to :

```
class GradientView: UIView{





    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }


    func addGradient(){
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor,UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.green.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradient.locations = [0,0.5,1]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }

}
```

[image]

Should look something like this. Maybe your gradient colours would look better.

Comment: Yes, but the GradientView itself is not what the question is about. The question is about masking an already present gradientView with a UITextField. That is where the answer is concentrated on. I did not care enough about the gradient view itself.

Comment: What about white background behind textView? @SWAT

Comment: In concept, your UITextView's text is now applied as a layer mask for another view, which contains a gradient sublayer. Which would mean that anything beyond the text itself will be invisible. But you can add this GradientView as a subLayer to any other View, with it's own backgroundColor, like a container View.